# MySQL: Combine 2 tables and calulate for sum value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I combine `book` and `sales_item` to calculate `sum(total_price)` group by same `isbn` (output like `result`). THX~

```
book
-----------------------------------------------------------
isbn   title    price
111    AAA      100     
222    BBB      90 
333    CCC      150

sales_item
-----------------------------------------------------------
bill_id  isbn  quantity  price    total_price
1        111   5         100      500
1        222   1         90       90
2        333   1         150      150
3        111   8         100      800



result
-----------------------------------------------------------
isbn   title   price  sum(total_price)
111    AAA     100    1300
222    BBB     90     90
333    CCC     150    150
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding the code that is not working

Comment: Geez -- it's not _that_ hard to see what Ming is asking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply group by isbn:

```
SELECT book.isbn, book.title, book.price, SUM(total_price) 
FROM sales_item, book 
WHERE book.isbn = sales_item.isbn GROUP BY isbn;
```

Comment: I would add: note that there is some redundancy between the two tables.  For example, sales_item.price isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

Try that?

```
select si.isbn, 
 MAX(b.title) as title, 
 MAX(b.price) as price, 
 sum(si.total_price) as total_price
From book b
inner join sales_item si on b.isbn = b.isbn
Group by si.isbn
```